# Call a method from a WCF Service through Excel VBA

Tags: wcf, excel, vba

I have created a method through a WCF webservice. I've uploaded it to my server. What I'd like to do is call that method in an Excel VBA macro. Is it possible?

Something like:

```
Dim client As DaybookServicesClient = New DaybookServicesClient()
' Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

' Calls my method
client.ExecuteSQLJob()

' Always close the client.
client.Close()
```

How would I reference my service in Excel VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one approach could be create WebGet wcf service,service would return adorecordset xml, on macro you can fetch recordset using following code

```
    Public Function GetRSFromString(sXML As String) As Object
   Dim oStream As Object, oRecordset As Object
   Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
   oStream.Open
   oStream.WriteText sXML
   oStream.Position = 0
   Set oRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   oRecordset.Open oStream
   oStream.Close
   Set oStream = Nothing
   Set GetRSFromString = oRecordset
   Set oRecordset = Nothing
End Function


Public Function GetSoapRequest()
    Dim strResult As String
    Dim xmlhtp As Object, xmlDoc As Object, oRecordSetFromXML As Object
    Set xmlhtp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp.6.0")
    With xmlhtp
            .Open "get", "http://[server]/ServiceName.svc/FunctionName", False
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            .Send
            Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
            strResult = .responseText
            xmlDoc.loadXML strResult
            Set oRecordSetFromXML = AdoFunction .GetRSFromString(xmlDoc.Text)
    End With
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing
    Set xmlhtp = Nothing               
End Function
```

Comment: The return type of my method `ExecuteSQLJob` is just a string to determine if it was successful or not, so I wouldnt need to returna recordSet would I?

Answer (score 0):

You can call web services from excel using the [Web Service Reference Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140260%28v=office.10%29.aspx) to generate a proxy for you service and then making a call in VBA code.

However, I have tried to get this working before and failed due to interoperability between VB and Java (which was hosting the service).

If your calls are one way (the VBA code doesn't require a response) it would be better to have the VBA code send a message via msmq to an intermediary service which will then make the call on your behalf. This is the solution I ended up using.